# I have a bytes list, how can I convert this to str in python2?

Tags: python

In java:

```
byte[] b = {50, 49, 54, 57, 54, 57, 52, 51};
String str = new String(b);
System.out.println(str);
```

result is `21696943`.
but how can I convert this `b` to str in python2?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string

Answer (score 1):

Use [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray)

```
>>> bytearray([50, 49, 54, 57, 54, 57, 52, 51])
bytearray(b'21696943')
>>> str(_)
'21696943'
```

Comment: 9s :-).  I guess I'm getting slower . . . +1

Comment: @mgilson, well you know sometimes people can't wait the extra 9s :)

Comment: I sure wouldn't want to :-)